# Mysql usar ou não o 'as' em aliases?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Escrevendo uma `query` em **MySQL** me deparei com essa duvida, fiz uma busca, porem, não achei nada (*ou não soube procurar*), a duvida é simples, existe alguma diferença entre usar ou não o **`as`** na hora de criar um nome temporário para a colunas do MySQL?

**Exemplo:**

No exemplo a baixo usei o `as` para definir o nome temporário:

```
SELECT nome_titulo as Titulo, nome_exibicao as 'Nome de Exibição' , created_at as 'Data de Criação' FROM moneyguard_database.titulos;
```

Já nesse exemplo eu não utilizei apenas passei o nome temporário ao lado:

```
SELECT nome_titulo Titulo, nome_exibicao 'Nome de Exibição' , created_at 'Data de Criação' FROM moneyguard_database.titulos;
```

Em ambos os casos eu tenho o mesmo resultado, será que existe alguma diferente em desempenho ou algum caso que uma forma seja melhor que a outra?

Desde já agradeço o esclarecimento.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do **MySQL**:

Uma expressão select pode receber um alias usando `AS alias_name`. O Alias é usado como o nome da coluna da expressão e pode ser usado em: `ORDER BY, GROUP BY ou HAVING`. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name) AS full_name   FROM mytable ORDER BY full_name;
```

A palavra-chave AS é opcional quando criando um alias em uma expressão `select` com um identificador. O exemplo anterior poderia ser escrito assim:

```
SELECT CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name) full_name   FROM mytable
ORDER BY full_name;
```

No entanto, como o **AS** é opcional, um problema que pode acontecer se você esquecer de colocar a vírgula entre dois itens do select: o **MySQL** vai interpretar o segundo nome como um alias. Por exemplo, na seguinte expressão, columnb é tratado como um alias:

```
SELECT columna columnb FROM mytable;
```

> **Por este motivo, é uma boa prática ter o hábito de usar AS quando especificando um alias de uma coluna.**